# Android views change on click

Tags: android, view

I need something simple, an ability to switch views in my app like I do in iPhone, 
for example I load first screen with button, click on this button and go next screen with an ability to go back ( We all see Back button in the iPhone UI ).
I've been trying to do startActivity(this,MySecondScreen.class) but it crashes.

```
public class mainClass extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void login_Click(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    try{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMenuTabs.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("main",ex.toString());
    }
}
```

}

and my second class is this which is a TabActivity extender
public class pissedoff extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenuview);
}

public void login_Click(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    try{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMenuTabs.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("main",ex.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide more information, especially code and crash log.

Comment: @user634618 there you go mate: try{
     Intent i = new Intent(this, MainMenuTabs.class);
     startActivity(i);
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
      Log.e("main",ex.toString());
     }
and the MainMenuTabs is a second screen that I want to switch to once clicking the button on the mainscreen, it is declared as 
public class MainMenuTabs extends TabActivity {
....
}
thanks

Comment: No, update your question with the code, don't paste it in the comments.

Comment: Yes but _what's the error_? (what does logcat say?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), YourNewClass.class); /** Class name here */
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

It might crash because in your android manifest file also have to declare activity like that:

```
<activity android:name="YourNewClass" android:label="YourNewClass"></activity>
```

Or use the built in grahpical thing. (Android manifest -> Application -> Application Nodes -> Add -> Activity)

Comment: that was it! thanks man, another quick one is when is it better to use ViewFlipper to flip views and when do I want to start a new activity? I mean what I eventually want is to be able to navigate between few screens and load different data from the server for each screen.

Comment: As far as I know, flipviewer is just used when you want to make animations to switch views with "sliding". I can't really tell what is the best for your project. Read more about flipviewer from here: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/ It's a really good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In Your XML, create a file for each view (makes it easier to work with), then in your main:

```
<ViewFlipper
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/vf">

    <include android:id="@+id/firstView" layout="@layout/first" />
    <include android:id="@+id/secondView" layout="@layout/second" />
    <include android:id="@+id/thirdView" layout="@layout/third" />
    <include android:id="@+id/fourthView" layout="@layout/fourth" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

in your java code:

```
ViewFlipper vf;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vf);
```

when you want to use the next view use `vf.showNext();`

Comment: @Rasman thanks for the answer, but can I skip one or more views and go directly from first to last and vice versa for example? I'm basically looking for something that is similar to the UIToolBar in iOs where I have buttons and on each button I create a dynamic new view where I can inside that view make URL calls, show table etc...

Comment: `.showPrevious()` goes back and I believe `.getChildAt(NUM)` gets the view you want based on the order... (although I'll need to doublecheck that)

Comment: @Rasman - that might be exactly what I need, my app is multiple view app that loads stuff from server and displays it, I still haven't got the difference between Activity and just View, I mean if using ViewFlipper I can change full screen views to whatever I want and load server data per view then I guess the ViewFlipper is the way to go, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm writing a program where each view does it's own little thing in it's own little world while using a few "global" objects. A few times I fetch data from a server...I don't know what the right answer is, but I had the same question you were asking, and I settled on this. I should note that vf wraps around (so if it's at the last view .next brings it back to the first)

Comment: @Rasman - settled on what?on using ViewFlipper you mean? I guess you also have separate .java class for each view right?so you can do some stuff inside each view including the server connectivity?

Comment: FTR, animation in viewflipper is a pretty option that I don't use. It can just load a screen end of story

Comment: @gal ya settled on ViewFlipper. Most of my code is in one file: each view has their own routine(s) but not class. I only used a class when I'm trying to do something tedious (like XMLparsing)

Answer (score 0):

1.This is how your Main Activity should look.Add button in the layout.

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button B;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent obj = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(obj);
                                         }

                                     }
                );
            }
        }
```

2. This is how your Next Activity should look.Use onBackpressed Method.

   ```
       public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);


       }
       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
           finish();
       }




   }
   ```

3.Hope it helps.